# Creating a custom window for GLUT?

Tags: c++, window, glut

Is there a method to create/specify a custom window for GLUT instead of using the glutCreateWindow method? I'd like to modify certain elements of the window, such as removing the border, possibly rounding the corners, etc.

There doesn't seem to be any built-in functions to set a certain `HWND` handle as the targetted GLUT window (on Windows).

Any ideas?
Jengerer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glut, and OpenGL which Glut is built on, are intended to be crossplatform. Every platform has it's own ideas about what makes a window. To work around this OpenGL has it's own concept of windows, or rendering contexts. A rendering context is a chunk of memory where a DIB (Device Independent Bitmap) is rendered, which generally doesn't include window decorations (The borders, the X, the window icon, etc...). Unless there are platform specific extension which I am not aware of there is no way to pass Glut an HWND, which is specific to windows.

You may be able to create a rendering context somewhere else, such as in your own code or in another library. Once created there may be a way to pass this context or a pointer to the context into Glut. OpenGL this supports and so do many libraries built on top of it.

I am not sure why you want to alter window decorations, if the situation allows it might be easier to use a library that supports this natively rather than rigging Glut into a solution. I know SDL, Ogre3d have limited abilities to control the window decorations (I don't think either can round the corners though), and if you really want to work with Glut it is possible to get either of those libraries to give you a pointer to the OpenGL rendering context they use. I haven't used QT but I know it provides easier access to the kind of control you want and will be able to create an OpenGL context for you.

However, after looking at the documentation for Glut at http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/spec3.html it does not use the word "context".  This might mean that if you use Glut you are limited to the window decoration tools it provides. Which might mean that you either have to drop glut and use a library which does more, or settle for the window decorations the OS provides.